# How to get response from Soap Object to string in android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have used the following code to get the response from .Net web service(asmx).

```
try{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet =true;
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    httpTransport.debug=true;
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    String Text = result.getProperty(1).toString();
        System.out.println("Text : "  + Text);
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I tried this code, I got the following output.

> anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{ResponseTable=anyType{Result=Success; }; };
>   }

Here, I would need "Result=Success".

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
String Result = result.getProperty(0).toString();
```

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the response from the Soap Object is, anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{ResponseTable=anyType{Result=Assigned; }; }; }; }

Answer (score 0):

The result like a multidimension array. You need parse the result until you get the last element: `Result=Assigned;`

First time: (`array` with 2 elements)

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject first = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
```

you will get as your comment:

> anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{elemen‌​t=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{};
>   }; }; }; }; }; }; };
>   diffgram=anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{ResponseTable=anyType{Result=Assigned;
>   }; }; }; }

Second Time: (`array[1]`)

```
SoapObject second = (SoapObject) first.getProperty(1);
```

you got:

> anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{ResponseTable=anyType{Result=Assigned;}; }; }

Third Time: (`array[1][0]`)

```
SoapObject third = (SoapObject) second.getProperty(0);
```

you got:

> anyType{ResponseTable=anyType{Result=Assigned;};}

And finally, Forth time: (`array[1][0][0]`)

```
SoapObject forth = (SoapObject) third.getProperty(0);
```

you will get which you want:

> anyType{Result=Assigned;}

Now using following to get your element: (`array[1][0][0][i]` this time `i=0`)

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
forth.getPropertyInfo(0, pi);
Log.d("MRNEO", pi.getName() + "=" + forth.getProperty(0).toString());
```

and the result in log is:

> Result=Assigned